# Kafka latency keeps increasing when running consumer on a different host

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have the Kafka producer running on host A, broker and consumer running on host B. The producer is sending at a rate of about 1500 messages/sec, with each message around 100 bytes in a topic with 1 partition only. The consumer is always in sync with producer meaning there is NO delay at all.
However, once move the consumer to host C, the latency keeps increasing from zero at the beginning to 30 min after 1 hour.
The ping test gives 100 ms between A and B, and 160ms between B and C.
The latency seems to come from the consumer, so I have made the following few tweaks on the consumer configuration but none of them reduced the latency, some even increased it.

1. Increase max.partition.fetch.bytes to 4194304 fetch.max.bytes to 209715200
2. Increase max.partition.fetch.bytes to 4194304 fetch.max.bytes to 209715200, and decrease fetch.max.wait.ms to 100 fetch.min.bytes=4096
3. Increase max.partition.fetch.bytes to 4194304 fetch.max.bytes to 209715200, and decrease fetch.max.wait.ms to 1 fetch.min.bytes=1

The consumer only prints the messages it receives, so latency is not caused by application logic or GC.

Could anyone give me pointers about what to look into?

Comment: I set this receive.buffer.bytes=512000 for consumer and now the consumer is always behind producer for 9 sec, which is much more predictable. However, why is there a 9 sec delay, can I reduce it further?

Comment: same latency using command-line consumer to rule out application issue or network issue.